# Possible to add attributes via NcML to non-cached THREDDS datasets?

Tags: ncml, thredds

For several years on our THREDDS Data Server (TDS) we've been happily using [the cache="false" functionality on datasetRoot](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/tds/reference/ThreddsConfigXMLFile.html) to tell the TDS *not* to cache several netcdf files.

```xml
  <service name="allServices" serviceType="Compound" base="">
    <service name="ncdods" serviceType="OpenDAP" base="/thredds/dodsC/"/>
    <service name="HTTPServer" serviceType="HTTPServer" base="/thredds/fileServer/"/>
    <service name="iso" serviceType="ISO" base="/thredds/iso/"/>
    <service name="uddc" serviceType="UDDC" base="/thredds/uddc/"/>
  </service>

  <datasetRoot path="FVCOM" location="/http/www/CODFISH/Data/FVCOM/" cache="false"/>

  <dataset name="NECOFS GOM2 Forecast" ID="gom2_nocache" serviceName="allServices"
    urlPath="FVCOM/NECOFS/Forecasts/NECOFS_GOM2_FORECAST.nc" dataType="Grid"/>
```

The reason we don't want to ever cache these files is that every day these daily forecast files get overwritten with files that have the same name, but different data.

But now we have a need to add and modify the attributes of these datasets.   In particular, we would like to add the global attribute

```xml
<attribute name="cdm_data_type" value="any"/>
```

Can we modify attributes via NcML when the dataset to be modified is contained in this kind of datasetRoot construct?